# Difference between an "Ordinary Least Square (OLS) model" and a "Panel Fixed- Effects (FE) model"

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, econometrics, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I recently ran into a paper that described the following:

> To test the robustness of each specification, we used a
>   difference-in-difference (DID) estimator to control for time invariant
>   factors that jointly affected control and treated units. We estimated
>   the DID with i) an Ordinary Least Square (OLS) model and with ii) a
>   Panel Fixed-Effects (FE) model.

Source: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0119881#sec002

It is my understanding that an OLS model is (or at least it can be) based on a panel data, where the covariates are treated as fixed effects, right? So what is the difference between the two models tested in the paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is economists' speech for saying that for $y_{it}$ being the observation for individual $i$ at time $t$ and $x_{it}$ being the regressor vector for individual $i$ at time $t$, they ran two models:
\begin{align}
 y_{it} & = \beta_0 + x_{it}^T\beta + \varepsilon_{it},
\end{align}
which they call OLS and for which $\beta_0$ is the overall intercept, and
\begin{align}
 y_{it} & = x_{it}^T\beta + \alpha_i + \varepsilon_{it},
\end{align}
which they call a *Fixed Effects Model* and for which $\alpha_i$ is the individual-specific intercept. The terminology is somewhat confusing, since you still estimate your Fixed Effects Model using the OLS estimator, but you will transform the data first using the within-transformation:
\begin{align}
y_{it} -\bar{y}_i & = (x_{it}^T - \bar{x}_i)\beta + (\alpha_i -\bar{\alpha}_i) + \varepsilon_{it},
\end{align}
which you apply to take out the individual-specific term $\alpha_i$. Since you expect it to be *fixed* across time, $\bar{\alpha}_i = \alpha_i$ and so the term vanishes when you run the actual regression. If you want to estimate the $\alpha_i$ terms, you can do that. Economists call the resulting model the *Random effects model*. This model has the problem that you need to estimate an additional parameter per individual, and thus your standard errors get larger as you have more individuals, which is why *Fixed Effects* are preferred if $N$ is large relative to $T$.

The difference is really only the inclusion of an individual-specific intercept term ($= \alpha_i$) to replace the overall intercept ($=\beta_0$). Usually, you try to capture individual-specific heterogeneity with the $\alpha_i$, so it serves as a kind of 'catch all' term. (E.g., if $y_{it}$ is the IQ and $x_{it}$ are some environmental factors, you could interpret $\alpha_i$ as a kind of catch-all term for an individual's genetic predisposition and any other unmeasured individual-specific variables that influence the IQ)

Comment: but then this individual-specific intercept term ends up acting a random effect term, no?

Comment: Good point, I skipped over the estimation details, but I included it now. I incorporated the difference between RE and FE too, hope that helps.

Comment: My understanding is the intercept terms $\alpha_i$ are random effects, which we're not interested in measuring for the study, but they account for much of the variation in $y_{it}$ so we want to control for them, is that correct?